# In Laravel how to pass parameters to a BelongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel

I have this relation in my User model:

```
public function groups() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Group', 'role_in_group')
                  ->orderBy('role_id', 'desc');
}
```

Obviously it returns the groups a user belongs to. So far, so good. But I have this role_in_group pivot table, I want to get the groups a user belongs to, but with an specific role, so I wrote this other function:

```
public function groupsAsAdmin() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Group', 'role_in_group')
                  ->whereIn('role_id', [15, 18, 19])
                  ->orderBy('role_id', 'desc');
}
```

And it works, but I think its a silly solution, I want to do something like:

```
public function groups(array $roles_id = NULL) {

  if (empty($roles_id)) {
    $id = [10, 15, 18, 19];
  }

  return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Group', 'role_in_group')
                  ->whereIn('role_id', $id)
                  ->orderBy('role_id', 'desc');
}
```

I **know** this must work. My problem is in the template.

If I ask for `$user->groups` it will return a collection, which is what I want, but if I ask for `$user->groups([19])` it will return a `belongsToMany` object, so it wont work inside `@foreach`

This will fail:

```
@foreach($user->groups([10, 15, 19]) as $group)
   {{ $group->id }}<br>
@endforeach
```

So, how can I call the `groups()` function in the model, and make it return a collection, as it would if I call it without the parenthesis? Is there a better way other than having two functions as I have it now?

Answer (score 1):

[Using the method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) instead of the property allows you to build the query.

```
$user->groups()->whereIn('role_id', [10, 15, 19])->get();
```

Or when fetching users using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$users = User::with(['groups' => function($query) {
    return $query->whereIn('role_id', [10, 15, 19]);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, that would go in the `@foreach`? Because that looks like requires the standard `groups()`, isn't it?

Comment: This is what I tried, and worked! (Based on your idea). I do `@foreach($user->groups([10, 15, 19])->get() as $group)`, so the answer on how to convert a `belongsToMany` object to a collection is to call the `->get()` on it. Thanks a lot!!!